# QT как отловить закрытие создоваемого QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt

Создаю такое диалоговое окно.

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                    tr("fu"), "fu",
                                                    tr("fu (*.fu)"));
```

Как отловить закрытие данного диалога, при нажатии на "Х" или при нажатии отмены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение.

```
if(filename.isEmpty()&& filename.isNull()){
  //что-то выполнить если диалоговое окно закрыто без выбора файла или через отмену.
}
```

Comment: Достаточно первого условия